# Not getting last updated value in Jtable Cell

Tags: java, swing

I am creating Java *Swing* UI. Following is my UI

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0gfc.png)

I am using `JTable` here. Here we are allowing user to update *Attribute* value.
So when I update *Age* it internally fires `setValueAt` method which updates the given, but when we update the second value, i.e. *Name* and after that click *Save* button, somehow I am not getting updated value of *Name*.

Reason is when I unclick *Name* row, in that case it internally fires `setValueAt` method. So any way to fire `setValueAt` method when I click button so that I can get the updated values?

**EDIT:**

Model Class

```java
public class StudentModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final Map<String, String> userProperty = new HashMap<>();
    private final String[] header = new String[]{"Attribute Name", "Attribute Value"};
    private String[] keys;

    public StudentModel(Map<String, String> attributeMap) {
        this.userProperty.putAll(attributeMap);
        keys = this.userProperty.keySet().toArray(new String[this.userProperty.size()]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return userProperty.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return header.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        if (col == 0) {
            return header[0];
        } else {
            return header[1];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex == 0) {
            return keys[rowIndex];
        } else {
            return userProperty.get(keys[rowIndex]);
        }
    }

    public void removeAllRows() {
        this.userProperty.clear();
        keys = this.userProperty.keySet().toArray(new String[this.userProperty.size()]);
    }

    public void addRow(Map<String, String> newRows) {
        this.userProperty.putAll(newRows);
        keys = this.userProperty.keySet().toArray(new String[this.userProperty.size()]);
    }

    public void updateTable() {
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return column == 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        userProperty.put(keys[row], String.valueOf(value));
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getAttributeMap() {
        return userProperty;
    }
}
```

**UI Class:**

```java
public class JTableDemo2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JButton addBtn;
    private JButton resetBtn;
    private JTable jtable;
    private StudentModel studentModel;

    private JTableDemo2() {
        setBounds(300, 200, 550, 400);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
        initializeComponent();
    }

    void initializeComponent() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        studentModel = new StudentModel(getDummyData());
        addBtn = new JButton("Save");
        addBtn.addActionListener(this);
        resetBtn = new JButton("Close");
        resetBtn.addActionListener(this);
        jtable = new JTable(studentModel);
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(jtable));
        panel.add(addBtn);
        panel.add(resetBtn);
        add(panel);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTableDemo2 object = new JTableDemo2();
        object.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Map<String, String> getDummyData() {
        Map<String, String> rowData = new HashMap<>();
        rowData.put("Age", "");
        rowData.put("Name", "");
        return rowData;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == addBtn) {
            System.out.println("studentModel.getAttributeMap() :" + studentModel.getAttributeMap());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output after clicking button:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wR0s.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the cell that you just edited is still in "edit mode" when you click on the *Save* button. Refer to this bug: [JDK-6349059](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6349059)

The bug states that the problem was solved by setting a [custom property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/jcomponent.html#properties). I assumed that the property is set when a `JTable` is created but according to my check, it is not. Hence I could reproduce your problem. Explicitly setting the property solves the problem. I suggest that you add the following line to method `initializeComponent` (of class `JTableDemo2`):

```java
jtable.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
```

Also note that the default [layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for [the content pane of] `JFrame` is [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) so I suggest adding the `JTable` to a `JScrollPane` and setting the `JScrollPane` as the "center" component. Consider the following code (which includes all the changes I suggested, above):

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class JTableDemo2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JButton addBtn;
    private JButton resetBtn;
    private JTable jtable;
    private StudentModel studentModel;

    private JTableDemo2() {
        setBounds(300, 200, 550, 400);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
        initializeComponent();
    }

    void initializeComponent() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        studentModel = new StudentModel(getDummyData());
        addBtn = new JButton("Save");
        addBtn.addActionListener(this);
        resetBtn = new JButton("Close");
        resetBtn.addActionListener(this);
        jtable = new JTable(studentModel);
        add(new JScrollPane(jtable), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(addBtn);
        panel.add(resetBtn);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        jtable.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTableDemo2 object = new JTableDemo2();
        object.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Map<String, String> getDummyData() {
        Map<String, String> rowData = new HashMap<>();
        rowData.put("Age", "");
        rowData.put("Name", "");
        return rowData;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == addBtn) {
            System.out.println("studentModel.getAttributeMap() :" + studentModel.getAttributeMap());
        }
    }
}
```

I also suggest that you refer to [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).